# How do you create a PKG file using Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode13, productbuild

I have an App built using Xcode 13, and I need this App to be packaged inside a PKG file as follows:

[image: Apple PKG Icon]

What is the expected way to do this?

Is there a target that can be added to an Xcode project that will generate a PKG file? If so, what is that target called?

I understand that productbuild is used to package an App into a PKG from the command line, and you would run this outside the Xcode project. Assuming no target exists to build a PKG, is this the expected way to build a PKG file?

Obviously I can script all of this up, but I don't want to make this more complicated than it needs to be if I've missed something obvious.